# How to remember checkbox choice after submit?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, checkbox

I use this code to check which tags are used within a Wordpress category. It renders a checkbox list. I want the form to remember my choice after submit.

This is my code:

```
<form name="tags" onChange="document.forms.tags.submit();">
    <?php
    if (is_category()){
      $cat = get_query_var('cat');
      $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
    }
    $tag_IDs = array();
    query_posts('category_name='.$yourcat->slug);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      $posttags = get_the_tags();
      if ($posttags):
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        if (!in_array($tag->term_id , $tag_IDs)):
           $tag_IDs[] = $tag->term_id; 
           $tag_names[$tag->term_id] = $tag->name;
           $tag_slug[$tag->term_id] = $tag->slug;
         endif;
        }
      endif;
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    if (!empty($tag_IDs)){
        echo '<h3>Het meest geschikt voor</h3>';
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"tag\" value=\"\"> Alles weergeven<br>";
    }
    foreach($tag_IDs as $tag_ID){
        echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$tag_slug[$tag_ID].'"> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Before I was using this code to remember the choice, but it doesn't work with the above code anymore:

```
if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "tag-example") { echo "checked";}
```

I thought it would work like this, but it doesn't:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$tag_slug[$tag_ID].'" '.if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "oudere-kinderen") { echo "checked";}.'> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';
```

How can I get the form to remember the checkbox choice?

## Solution:

With help from @Jouke I came to this solution:

`if (is_category()){
          $cat = get_query_var('cat');
          $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
        }
        $tag_IDs = array();
        query_posts('category_name='.$yourcat->slug);
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
          $posttags = get_the_tags();
          if ($posttags):
            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            if (!in_array($tag->term_id , $tag_IDs)):
               $tag_IDs[] = $tag->term_id; 
               $tag_names[$tag->term_id] = $tag->name;
               $tag_slug[$tag->term_id] = $tag->slug;
             endif;
            }
          endif;
        endwhile; endif;
        wp_reset_query();
        if (!empty($tag_IDs)){
            echo '<h3>Het meest geschikt voor</h3>';
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"tag\" value=\"\"> Alles weergeven<br>";
        }
        foreach($tag_IDs as $tag_ID){
            $test = $tag_slug[$tag_ID];
            echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$test.'"' ;
            if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == $test) {
            echo ' checked="checked"';
            }
            echo '> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function([wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked)):

```
<?php checked( $checked, $current, $echo ); ?>
```

Example:

```
<input type='radio' name='tag' value='1' <?php checked(isset($variable)); ?>>variable
```

Another example(php):

```
$test=test;
echo "<input type='radio' name='tag' value='$test' checked( isset( $test ) ); >";
```

With escaping:

```
$tagslug = $tag_slug[$tag_ID];
echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value=/"$tagslug/" checked( isset( $tagslug ) );>';
```

Another example without the wordpress function checked:
Paste it in [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and test it

```
$test = "slug";
echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="$test"' ;
if (isset($test)) {
echo 'checked="checked"';
}
echo '>';
```

Comment: If I use `echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$tag_slug[$tag_ID].'" '.checked(isset($tag_slug[$tag_ID])).'> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';` then `checked='checked'` is shown on the page itself.

Comment: It's supposed to output <input type='radio' name='tag' value='1' checked> not checked='checked' but just checked

Comment: It only gives `checked='checked'` for each tag, so on the page itself (not only in the source code) I see for example ten times the line `checked='checked'` if there are ten tags.

Comment: Added another example. Just delete what you have and try this and edit it to your variable.

Comment: I tried it, but I the output is also `checked='checked'` which is displayed on the page itself. See the screenshot http://oi61.tinypic.com/1y2ryu.jpg. As the variable I use `$tag_slug[$tag_ID]`, but even when I use something else it also displays `checked='checked'`.

Comment: I forgot to close the tag with another > add this

Comment: I use this code: `echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$tag_slug[$tag_ID].'" '.checked( isset( $tag_slug[$tag_ID] ) ).'> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';` but it gives also `checked='checked'` on the page itself. I also tried `$test=test;` `echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$tag_slug[$tag_ID].'" '.checked( isset( $test ) ).'> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';` but with the same result.

Comment: And checked is a php function so it doesn't have to be inbetween '' since your using this in an echo(php). Added an example with escaping

Comment: Added another example without the wordpress checked function

Comment: Thanks @Jouke! I modified your last code a little bit and came to this solution: `foreach($tag_IDs as $tag_ID){
   $checked = $tag_slug[$tag_ID];
   echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$checked.'"' ;
   if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == $checked) {
   echo ' checked="checked"';
   }
   echo '> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'<br>';
  }`

Comment: Glad it finally worked! Please accept the answer so it's removed from the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> echo '<input type="radio" name="tag" value="'.$tag_slug[$tag_ID].'" '.if((isset($_POST["tag"])) && $_POST["tag"] == "oudere-kinderen") { echo "checked=checked";}.'> '.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'
> ';